# react-native init erro relacionado ao proxy

Tags: react, react-native

Não estou conseguindo configurar meu primeiro app, é algo relacionado ao proxy, mas não faço ideia de como resolver isso já pesquisei em tudo que é lugar alguem sabe como resolver?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quando você acessa o endereço https://registry.npmjs.org/ retorna algo(JSON) ?